# Pyspark reading from HDFS error: An error occurred while calling o32.csv

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I have a csv file in HDFS and am trying to load it into a Spark dataframe, using a pyspark a python script in EMR.

I get the following error (full error at the end)

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.csv
```

Here is how I am attempting to do it

```
df = spark.read.csv("http://localhost:9870/foo/tsla_202210_min.csv", schema = stockSchema)
```

Have I set something incorrectly in the filepath?

---

Full error

```
File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 535, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.csv.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.AbstractHttpFileSystem.listStatus(AbstractHttpFileSystem.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpFileSystem.listStatus(HttpFileSystem.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.listLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.$anonfun$parallelListLeafFilesInternal$1(HadoopFSUtils.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFilesInternal(HadoopFSUtils.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Tried changing the address and ports of where to find HDFS on the EMR, but still no luck

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
This line kind of suggests that the file is unreadable, I'm not sure though

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had incorrectly set the filepath. Found out how to set it correctly following [this article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-write-files-from-hdfs-txt-csv-avro-parquet-json/)

Specifically

> Unlike other filesystems, to access files from HDFS you need to provide the Hadoop name node path, you can find this on Hadoop core-site.xml file under Hadoop configuration folder. On this file look for fs.defaultFS property and pick the value from this property. for example, you will have the value in the below format. replace nn1home and port from the value in fs.defaultFS property.

From there, to find the `.xml` I used [this](https://data-flair.training/forums/topic/what-are-the-configuration-files-in-hadoop/)